# Android Studio ClassValue type?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-7

I am currently working on an android studio project. I am wondering if it's possible to use the type ClassValue in an Android Studio project.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassValue.html

I am running JDK 1.7, but somehow my ClassValue type is telling 
"Cannot resolve ClassValue."

Comment: `ClassValue` is not part of the Android Platform APIs (yet, hopefully it will be in Android N).